# Issue with passing values from Form and Controller to Blade in Laravel

Tags: laravel, model, controller, laravel-blade

I have issue with send values from address localhost/product/1/1 to my database, I want attach product 1 to customer 1 and add special prices below I add code

Route:

```
Route::get('/product/{customerID}/{productID}', 'CustomerController@insertCustomerProductForm')->name('add-product');
Route::post('/product/{customerID}/{productID}', 'CustomerController@insertCustomerProductAction');
to Controller
```

insertCustomerProductForm method:

```
public function insertCustomerProductForm($customerID, $productID)

{       
       return view('customer_products.create', [
        'customer' => Customer::find('$customerID'),
        'product' => Product::find('$productID'),        ]);    }
```

insetCustomerProductAction method:

```
public function insertCustomerProductAction (Request $request, $customerID, $productID) {        

    $newCustomerProduct = new CustomerProduct;
    $newCustomerProduct->product_id = $productID;
    $newCustomerProduct->customer_id = $customerID;
    $newCustomerProduct->selling_customer_price = $request->input('selling_customer_price'); 
    $newCustomerProduct->purchase_customer_price = $request->input('purchase_customer_price'); 
    $newCustomerProduct->consumed_customer_price = $request->input('consumed_customer_price'); 
    $newCustomerProduct->save();    }
```

Model CustomerProduct

```
class CustomerProduct extends Model
{
public function customers()

{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class);

}

public function products()

{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);

}}
```

and when I try use in blade set values for product of customer I have only from form values (selling_customer_price... etc) nothing about product and customer? I don't know why or this find method is problem? Because I have to store special price for special customer in this form.

below I add part of blade code

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Dodaj Produkt') }}  </div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="post">
                        @csrf

                <div class="form-group row">
                          {{ $customer }}



                   <label for="selling_customer_price " class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Cena Sprzedaży') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="selling_customer_price " type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('selling_customer_price ') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="selling_customer_price " value="" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('selling_customer_price '))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('selling_customer_price ') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
```

my error looking like it don't see variables from form:

`selling_customer_price`, `purchase_customer_price`, `consumed_customer_price`

I have error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'selling_customer_price' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `customer_products` (`product_id`, `customer_id`, `selling_customer_price`, `purchase_customer_price`, `consumed_customer_price`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 1, , , , 2018-07-09 12:39:03, 2018-07-09 12:39:03))
```

Comment: Why are you quoting the variables? `Customer::find('$customerID')` '$customerId'?

Answer (score 1):

Where exactly is your error coming from in both cases? `insertCustomerProductForm` should be working fine, as long as you pass the right parameters in the URL like so: `localhost/product/20/10`

POST request generally don't need parameters in the URL itself. You can retrieve the POST variables by doing `$_POST['selling_customer_price']` in your `insertCustomerProductAction` method.

Comment: I've just edited my post and wrote my issue. I used localhost/product/20/10 address by I can't got any information about customer and product and it isn't wrote in database, I don't know why

Comment: Can you show what you get when you do `var_dump($request->input('selling_customer_price')); die();` in your `insertCustomerProductAction` method?

Comment: I have /home/vagrant/code/app/Http/Controllers/CustomerController.php:306:null after var_dump